# mybatis annotation config for stored procedure with cursor result

Tags: java, mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

I am new to mybatis and i have a question.
I have a Oracle stored procedure that returns a CURSOR.

I don't understand how i can write the resultSet with annotations.

If i try this,

```java
@Mapper
public interface Message{

    @Select(value="{ #{OUT,javaType=java.sql.ResultSet,resultMap=messageQueryResult,jdbcType=CURSOR,mode=OUT} = call get_messages() }")
    @Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
    @ResultMap("messageQueryResult")
    List<Message> getMessages();
}
```

```xml
<mapper namespace="de.foo.mapper.Message">
    <resultMap id="messageQueryResult" type="de.foo.mapper.MessageValue">
    
            <result column="ID" javaType="java.lang.Long" />
            <result column="NOTE" javaType="java.lang.String" />

    </resultMap>
</mapper>
```

```java
public class MessageValue{

    private Long id;
    private String note;
}
```

```java
FUNCTION get_messages
  RETURN cursorType
  IS 
    c_messages  cursorType;
    sqlstring   VARCHAR2(4000);
  BEGIN
    sqlstring :=  'SELECT id, note FROM '||
                             ' vmessage WHERE ID IN ( ' ... ')';                                           

    OPEN cmessage FOR sqlstring;
    RETURN cmessage;
  END get_messages;
```

I get an error

```
org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no setter for property named 'OUT' in 'class java.lang.Class'
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is there a possibility to write the XML mapper in annotations?

Comment: MyBatis currently does not support Oracle's implicit cursor (i.e. `DBMS_SQL.return_result`). You may have to use `OUT` parameter to receive `SYS_REFCURSOR`. Here is an executable [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-56834806). If you don't use implicit cursor, please add the procedure definition to the question.

Comment: I added procedure to the question

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix a few things.

1. You must specify `property` attributes in the result map.

   ```xml
   <resultMap id="messageQueryResult" type="de.foo.mapper.MessageValue">
     <result column="ID"  property="id" />
     <result column="NOTE" property="note" />
   </resultMap>
   ```
2. To receive the result as an OUT parameter, the method needs a parameter.
   I use `Map` as the parameter. You can use a POJO with a property `out` if you prefer.
   Also, the method's return type should be `void` and `@ResultMap` should be removed.

   ```java
   @Select({
     "{ #{OUT,",
     "javaType=java.sql.ResultSet,", 
     "resultMap=messageQueryResult,", 
     "jdbcType=CURSOR,", 
     "mode=OUT} = call get_messages() }" })
   @Options(statementType = StatementType.CALLABLE)
   void getMessages(Map<String, Object> param);
   ```

After the execution, the result will be set to the parameter, so here is how you use it, basically.

```java
Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<>();
mapper.getMessages(param);
List<MessageValue> messages = (List<MessageValue>) param.get("OUT");
...
```

I assumed that `cursorType` means `SYS_REFCURSOR`, by the way.

---

Regarding your last question, it is possible to define the result map using annotations `@Results` and `@Result` (documentation is [here](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/java-api.html#Mapper_Annotation_Examples)).
Your case is a little bit tricky because MyBatis uses annotated method's return type when building result map. So, instead of annotating `getMessage()` method, you may need to add another mapper method like the following.

```java
@Results(id = "messageQueryResult", value = {
  @Result(column = "ID", property = "id"),
  @Result(column = "NOTE", property = "note")
})
@Select("select ID, NOTE from vmessage where ID = #{id}")
MessageValue getById(@Param("id") Long id);
```

This result map has the same ID, so you can remove the `<resultMap />` from the XML mapper and it should work.

Comment: thank you so much, this works for me. 
Yes ```cursorType``` means ```SYS_REFCURSOR```
Is there a way to define resultMap as Java annotations instead of XML?

Comment: @tine  I had missed your last question. Please see the updated answer.